# Progress of loading external JS file

Tags: javascript, progress-bar, dynamic-loading

I'm not sure what this would be called to know what to search for, if this is a duplicate please link me :)

Is it possible in JavaScript in a browser, to load an external file (this bit is easy), but given that the external file could be rather large (say 50MB) show a progress indicator of the loading of that file?

i.e I, knowing the serverside size of the file, not knowing the gzip size, I want to say X% of file loaded.

I've not tried anything, I can't find anything to work from let alone find something that suggests its possible.

**Problem:** Trying to load up a 50MB JavaScript library on demand but show the progress of the loading.

Comment: 50MB is huge! Is there any way to split this up into multiple files? Or reduce the size somehow?

Comment: @CameronTinker - http://bgrins.github.io/videoconverter.js/ this is the library. I want to do pre-upload video file checking :)

Comment: That's impressive! I will have to research this some more! I see on their website, they have a loading image indicating that the library is loading.

Comment: Related issue https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/issues/613

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use XMLHttpRequest to load the script and [monitor its progress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress). When it's done, `eval()` it.